# Issue with Salesforce (openld) authentication on a java Android app

Tags: java, android, authentication, salesforce

First of all, sorry for my poor english as it is not my native language.

So my coworkers set up a Salesforce authentication via openld on a Java Android app. The auth demand gets us back a valid access_token, which allows us to obtain informations on the Salesforce API.

The problem is that when the user disconnects from the application, the connexion is still active and doesn't ask again for user's password, which is an obvious security issue. Do you know how we could force a new authentication each time the user disconnects ?

We already tried token revocation but it also revokes every rights from the user, which doesn't satisfy us. We just need the app to ask for a login after a disconnection.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce SDK saves the login details in preferences, thus it doesn't ask for authentication the next time user visits the app. You can logout of Saleforce to clear the saved data using this:

```
SalesforceSDKManager.getInstance().logout(this);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! Actually, we don't use Salesforce SDK but Google's AppAuth. How can I make it work with it ? Sorry, I should have said that in my post.

Comment: It seems there is no logout support for AppAuth. A lot of issues are raised for that. Check if the app stores the credentials in app preferences. Maybe clearing the prefs will solve your problem? But not sure how this will affect your session or auth token.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll see if I can make that work.